# Java algorithm to split a list in buckets all combinations

Tags: java, algorithm

How can I split the contents of an array into two buckets and get all the combinations?

For example:
Array [A, B, C]

```
Bucket 1      Bucket 2
-             ABC
A             BC
BC            A
AB            C
C             AB
AC            B
B             AC
ABC           -
```

The number of permutations follow the formula: 2^N, where N is the length of the array.

Here is the code I have so far. However it does not go through all the possible combinations:

```
  for(int i=0; i<=testPortfolioArray.length; i++) {
      Object[] bucket1 = Arrays.copyOfRange(testPortfolioArray, 0, i);
      Object[] bucket2 = Arrays.copyOfRange(testPortfolioArray, i, testPortfolio.size());
      if(i>0 && i<testPortfolioArray.length) {
          bucket1 = Arrays.copyOfRange(testPortfolioArray, i, testPortfolio.size());
          bucket2 = Arrays.copyOfRange(testPortfolioArray, 0, i);
      }
  }
```

Comment: Please supply any code, logic and processes you've followed to achieve this and we can suggest where you might improve or investigate. Firstly being how would you, mathematically, achieve what you want to do?

Comment: As a hint: just find all possible subsets and put them in both buckets. For example "A - BC" is the same as "BC - A" just the parts are in different buckets. No need to calculate that specific subset twice.

Answer (score 0):

Think first about the data structures you want to represent your solution:
For one division of the objects, each object is either in bucket 1 or in bucket 2, so this can be described using a single bit.  Then, if you have n objects to divide, a division can be represented by a string of n bits.

Using that data structure, the set of all divisions consists of all lists of n binary digits, with the mapping that item i is in bucket 1 if the i-th bit is 0 and is in bucket 2 if the i-th bit is 1.

Does that give you what you're after?